# Sort based on two filters

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers

I have the following dashboard:

[image]

Those two pieces in red, are both from the same column. What I'm trying to do, is to filter this visualization with a single selection from both. However, when I select one from each filter, my visualization disappears...

I have deactivated the relationship between them, but yet no idea how to perform this...

Comment: If I understand correct, you are applying a filter like - WHERE country = 'A' and country = 'B'. This will never return you any row.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to set a filter like WHERE country = 'A' OR country = 'B'!

Comment: Then you have to use one slicer with multiple selection enabled. Two slicer always use AND in between.